# Multivariate, multi-step LSTM time series forecasting with Keras, Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I have a couple of questions regarding the logic behind multivariate, multi-step time series forecasting. To better illustrate, I am going to use an example:

Imagine I want to predict future closing prices for a stock given the past 60 days of data for closing price, opening price, and volume for that stock. I want to predict the closing price for the next 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 days. My questions are as follow:

1. During training, should I give as input all features (closing price, opening price, volume) for the past 60 days and make the model predict all features one day into the future? Mind you, the only thing I care about is predicting the future closing price, so I believe this strategy might ruin the loss function? Should I instead give the same input, but make the model predict the closing price for the next 1-5 days? In that case, the loss function will only take the closing price into account, but the model won't use predicted values to predict future values, e.g use prediction for day 1 to give a prediction for day 2. What is best here?
2. I know there is no clear cut answer for this, but I wonder what model architecture suits best for this purpose. Particularly, I wonder how many neurons to include in the LSTM layers, and how many LSTM layers to use. Also, is it always a good idea to have the final layer be a Dense layer with the number of neurons equal to the amounts of outputs you're expecting from the model?

Comment: probably you are looking for [this or similar](https://github.com/AtrCheema/dl4seq/blob/master/tests/test_models_using_targets.py#L47) case using [NBeats](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.10437.pdf) model.